# Default Icon List of Angular Material 2+

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular-material2

I need to see a default list of Icons for Angular Material 
https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview

I am not using Font Awesome and Google Fonts

Comment: @angular/material 's mat-icon dose not come with any icons, its designed to be used with an icon font. By default it's configured to work with Material Icons font from google fonts api. IE you need a <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an official list of all mat-icons in Angular?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50637666/is-there-an-official-list-of-all-mat-icons-in-angular)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Angular Material Icon component actually isn't pre-loaded with the Google Material Design Icons, I'm afraid.

According to the documentation for [Icon overview](https://material.angular.io/components/icon/overview#font-icons-with-ligatures):

> By default, `<mat-icon>` *expects* the [Material icons font](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#icon-font-for-the-web). (You will still need to include the HTML to load the font and its CSS, as described in the link).

<sub>This is located under the "Font icons with ligatures" header. I'm also emphasizing on the word *"expects"* here</sub>

And it even states under the [Getting Started guide](https://material.angular.io/guide/getting-started#step-6-optional-add-material-icons) that you should add the Material Icons font to your `index.html`:

> If you want to use the mat-icon component with the official Material Design Icons, load the icon font in your index.html.

So, you **have to** load an icon font (or an SVG iconset) in your app. You'll have to do it yourself.

Here's some font icons/ SVG icons you can use:

- Font icons

  - [Google's Material Icons](https://google.github.io/material-design-icons) and a list on [Material.io](https://material.io/tools/icons)
  - [Fontawesome (list of icons included in website)](https://fontawesome.com)
- SVG icons

  - [Templarian's Material Design Icons (list of icons included in website)](https://materialdesignicons.com)

Comment: No, you're wrong. There are default icons ready to be used by name. Read my answer here (it has a list of Angular Material icons): https://stackoverflow.com/a/64215719/6166911

Answer (score 9):

Is [this](https://material.io/icons/) what you're looking for?

Comment: well I am looking for a list where I can select icons available and choose from them  is there a web page which list them

Answer (score 0):

If you going to use Lars [answer](https://material.io/resources/icons). The following code will set the icon in your angular project

```
<span class="material-icons">home</span>
```